# time_bucket with start, end time

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, timescaledb

I have this kind of data

```
machine,start,end
A, 00:00, 00:01
B, 00:01, 00:02
C, 00:00, 00:03
```

and I want to aggregate for drawing the chart

```
start, end, value
00:00, 00:01, 2
00:01, 00:02, 2
00:02, 00:03, 1
```

The value is How many machine works in start-end duration. I tried to use `time_bucket_gapfill()`

but this function only use one column. which function I should use for this?

thanks.

------------- more example

```
machine,start,end
A, 00:00:00, 00:01:00
F, 00:00:30, 00:01:30
B, 00:01:00, 00:02:00
C, 00:00:00, 00:03:00
```

result should be

```
start, end, value
00:00, 00:01, 3
00:01, 00:02, 3
00:02, 00:03, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you can do this by unpivoting the rows, then counting:

```
select 
    x.tt as t_start, 
    lead(x.tt) over(order by x.tt) as t_end, 
    sum(sum(cnt)) over(order by x.tt) val
from mytable t
cross join lateral (values (t.t_start, 1), (t.t_end, -1)) x(tt, cnt)
group by x.tt
```

Comment: I think the query is missing a `group by` - see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aCBEiYx8iuzmnbt9fcWsE9/0)

Answer (score 1):

Generate minute intervals using `generate_series()`, then `left join`:

```
select m.minute as start,
       m.minute + interval '1 minute' as end,
       count(t.machine)
from (select generate_series(min(start), max(end), interval '1 minute') as minute
      from t
     ) m left join
     t
     on m.minute < t.end and
        m.minute >= t.start
group by m.minute
order by m.minute;
```

Note that `start` and `end` is a really bad choices for column names (because they are either keywords or reserved words in SQL).  I assume the real names are something else.

This is assuming that the values are stored as `time` or `datetime` values.

EDIT:

If your values are MM:SS, then:

```
select m.second as start,
       m.second + interval '1 second' as end,
       count(t.machine)
from (select generate_series(min('00:' || start), max('00:' || end), interval '1 second') as second
      from t
     ) m left join
     t
     on m.second < t.end and
        m.second >= t.start
group by m.second
order by m.second;
```

Comment: i added more example, could you please check that? thanks alot

Comment: @rura6502 . . . Just replace "minute" with "second" in the logic.